# postgres sometimes will not start after reboot

Tags: postgresql

Something weird is happening with my postgres installation after I upgraded to version 9.3.2 homebrew.

Sometimes and not every time,  if I enter `psql` I get this error message:

> > could not connect to server: No such file or directory
> >         Is the server running locally and accepting
> >         connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

It also appears that postgres is running because if I try and stop postgres with this command:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast`

I get this response:

> pg_ctl: server does not shut down

If I look in the `server.log` I can see the following entries:

> FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists HINT:  Is another
>   postmaster (PID 208) running in data directory
>   "/usr/local/var/postgres"?

After some frantic googling, I am able to cure this by entering these commands:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

I would like to first of all understand what is happening and second of all I would like to fix it once and for all.

Can anyone explain what might be happening and a cure?

Comment: Update. File name changed. But I just went to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and deleted `com.postgresapp.Postgres2LoginHelper.plist` manually and all was well with Postgres. My problem was almost certainly the result of  a crash. Didn't need to do the unload, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to pull up a log on PostgreSQL, on OSX (and with PG 9.3) this will most likely be here:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/pg_log
```

Check this log and see if there are any entires in it that may explain more of what is happening. Post it here or in a past bin somewhere. This can help the community to debug the issue.

Next, the reason why 'pg_ctl' says the server is not shutdown is because you have a stale socket file and/or a stale .plist file that did not get removed on last shutdown. This may indicate that the PostgreSQl daemon was "crashed" or was shutdown by force and did not have a clean finish.

The commands you used removed the stale files and thus made way for a new socket file to be created.

Also it is important to know if this was a minor or a major upgrade of PostgreSQL. Major upgrades *always* require a migration of the data directory. Running an old PostgreSQL data directory with a new engine might have unexpected results.

Comment: I have updated the post.

The log file contains these entries:

FATAL: lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists 
HINT: Is another postmaster (PID 208) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?

Comment: @dagda1 Thank you for the update, this is, however, not more helpful. It states indeed that there is a stale .pid file which did not get cleaned. As I have asked in my answer, was this a minor or major upgrade? Could it be possible that you still have the *old* PostgreSQL running in your Homebrew environment?

Comment: THis bug has just hit me again and the fix I posted in my article does not work this time.  The log says this:

FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists

How can I tell if another instance is running?

Comment: Excuse my late reply, Homebrew systems on OSX are a bit of unknown terrain for me, but to check if you have another instance of PostgreSQL running, you could check the "Activity Monitor" of OSX to see if there are any daemons (processes) running that belong to PostgreSQL. This, out of the top of my head, would be the next best thing to check.